# Authentication Agent Error in OpenShift

Tags: python, ssh, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a simple python flask web application in OpenShift,

But after deploying the application I'm getting "500 Internal Server error" when i try to access the url and the following error is thrown in the server log,

```
 rhc tail -a app -l mail -p password
```

[image]

Comment: Have you inserted your public key on the openshift web console?

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves Yeah, I have added the public ssh key but still no luck.